# Compiling CFLAGS in a Yocto Recipe File

Tags: make, c, yocto, bitbake

**Issue:** I have 2 macros I added in a c file and I have 2 machines. Using Yocto recipe I wish to build the code with specific macros for specific machines.

Breaking down the issue in sub parts -
**hello.c**

```
// Simple hello.c program
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    //Introducing Macro 1 -- abc

    #ifdef abc
    printf("Day 1\n");
    #endif

    //Introducing Macro 2 -- xyz

    #ifdef xyz
    printf("Day 2\n");
    #endif
}
```

**Expected & Observed Output:**

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
./hello
Hello World!

gcc hello.c -Dabc -o test1
./test1
Hello World!
Day 1 

gcc hello.c -Dxyz -o test2
./test2
Hello World!
Day 2
```

**Makefile Contents:**

```
obj-m := hello.o

SRC := ${shell pwd}

CFLAGS += -Dabc

all:
    ${MAKE} -C M=${SRC} ${CFLAGS}

test_install:
    ${MAKE} -C M=${SRC} ${CFLAGS} test_install

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Have checked the above Makefile contents using `cat -e -t Makefile`. It is properly terminated with $ at end of each line.
Since I am using MAKE, it does have the gcc compiler.
In the Makefile I have hardcoded CFLAGS="-Dabc" , intention being if the code is compiled accordingly then I can add ifeq condition to the Makefile handle the other CFLAGS="-Dxyz"

**Recipe File Contents:**

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/helloworld/hello"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "oldmachine|newmachine"
EXTRA_OEMAKE_oldmachine += "CFLAGS=-Dabc"
EXTRA_OEMAKE_newmachine += "CFLAGS=-Dxyz"

do_compile(){
    ${EXTRA_OEMAKE}_${MACHINE}
}
```

The default function of do_compile is to run oe_runmake, I assumed that it will be picking up this CFLAGS which I am trying to pass.

I checked the contents of the log.do_compile under tmp/work/... folder and I do not see the CFLAGS being used.

The above recipe I also re-wrote as

```
do_compile_append_oldmachine(){
     CFLAGS="-Dabc"
}

do_compile_append_newmachine(){
     CFLAGS="-Dxyz" #Also tried passing EXTRA_OEMAKE_MACHINE as above
}
```

This method also, unable to find the CFLAGS part when I check the log.do_compile file under tmp/work/.. directory.

How do I make use the CFLAGS so that it compiles the code as per the specific architecture?

**Misc Details:**

Under the specific meta layer, I have the directory like this.

helloworld

- hello.c
- hello.o
- Makefile

Note: Due to less rep, could not add CFLAGS as a tag for this.

Comment: If you write your own `do_compile`, doesn't it overwrite the default? So you need to actually call `oe_runmake`, not just `${EXTRA_OEMAKE}_${MACHINE}`. I wonder, why this didn't produce an error, but I'm not experienced with yocto.